# Excel copy format between cells using formulas

Tags: excel

Hy everybody,
I have a question about the cell formatting in excel. I have a table like that, where I have a series of true/false values:

[image]

Next I have another page in which I use a formula to determine if a 1 on a row is present and copy it to a single vertical table, like that:

[image]

That is pretty simple, by using a nested if I can easily achieve this result. Here is an example:

`=IF(PAG1!A1=1; PAG1!A1; IF(PAG1!B1=1; PAG1!B1; IF(...)))`

So I can stop on the first one. Now the problem is that I have a series of colors that must be copied too. As you can see from the picture I need to copy also the green and the red from the table, because at last I need a result similar to this one:

[image]

Is there a way to obtain this result programmatically? Green and red ones can be everywhere each time the table changes so I need a way to copy the format dinamically. Actually my idea is to try to get somehow the cell reference from the if statement (any clue on that point?) and once having the origin cell try to copy the format for the new cell in the new page. Is there a better way to do that?

At least it will be good also to have another table where I report the cell reference, like: D1, A2 and B3, so I can write a VBA script to color the cell based on their origin. Is there a function taht can be used to achieve that?

Comment: For the formula you can use the `OR()` function to have `=OR(A1,B1,C1,D1)` which is much simpler

Comment: @JAlex you could even just do `=--OR(A1:D1)`.

Comment: @BigBen yes, `--OR(<cell range>)` is a much better option as it convers the `TRUE`/`FALSE` values into `0` and `1`.

Comment: Note that a user defined function cannot alter the appearance of a cell, only affect it's value. So you are forced to run a subroutine that does the logic and coloration instead of using a function.

Answer (score 0):

Table where each row might have a single `1` on one of the columns starting at `A2` for example, with 4 columns. Find the column where `1` might exist use the `=MATCH()` function

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **2** | `0` | `0` | `1` | `0` |  | `=MATCH(1.0,A2:D2,0)` |
| **3** | `1` | `0` | `0` | `0` |  | `=MATCH(1.0,A3:D3,0)` |
| **4** | `0` | `0` | `0` | `0` |  | `=MATCH(1.0,A4:D4,0)` |

This will return the index in the range where a match is made, or `N/A`

| F |
| --- |
|  |
| `3` |
| `1` |
| `N/A` |

In this case the range includes columns **A** through **D** so `3=C` and `1=A`.

You can take it from here with VBA to find the cell in the table from each row and column information.